# Extract info inside all parenthesis in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a character string and what to extract the information inside of multiple parentheses.  Currently I can extract the information from the last parenthesis with the code below.  How would I do it so it extracts multiple parentheses and returns as a vector?

```
j <- "What kind of cheese isn't your cheese? (wonder) Nacho cheese! (groan) (Laugh)"                                                          
sub("\\).*", "", sub(".*\\(", "", j))
```

Current output is:

```
[1] "Laugh"
```

Desired output is:

```
[1] "wonder" "groan"  "Laugh"
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
> gsub("[\\(\\)]", "", regmatches(j, gregexpr("\\(.*?\\)", j))[[1]])
[1] "wonder" "groan"  "Laugh"
```

I think this should work well:

```
> regmatches(j, gregexpr("(?=\\().*?(?<=\\))", j, perl=T))[[1]]
[1] "(wonder)" "(groan)"  "(Laugh)"
```

but the results includes parenthesis... why?

This works:

```
regmatches(j, gregexpr("(?<=\\().*?(?=\\))", j, perl=T))[[1]]
```

Thanks @MartinMorgan for the comment.

Comment: NOTE: This will work for a vector but will not work for text in a column of a data frame.

Comment: @kohske & @SamFirke: I am genuinely curious, wouldn't something like `regmatches(j, gregexpr("\\(.*?\\)", text = j))` work just fine? why do you use lookarounds to solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: @AudileF to make it work for a column in a dataframe use unlist(regmatches(…)) before reassigning it back to the column of a dataframe.

Answer (score 32):

Using the stringr package we can reduce this a little bit.

```
library(stringr)
# Get the parenthesis and what is inside
k <- str_extract_all(j, "\\([^()]+\\)")[[1]]
# Remove parenthesis
k <- substring(k, 2, nchar(k)-1)
```

@kohske uses regmatches but I'm currently using 2.13 so don't have access to that function at the moment.  This adds the dependency on stringr but I think it is a little easier to work with and the code is a little clearer (well... as clear as using regular expressions can be...)

Edit: We could also try something like this -

```
re <- "\\(([^()]+)\\)"
gsub(re, "\\1", str_extract_all(j, re)[[1]])
```

This one works by defining a marked subexpression inside the regular expression.  It extracts everything that matches the regex and then gsub extracts only the portion inside the subexpression.

Answer (score 22):

I think there are basically three easy ways of extracting multiple capture groups in R (without using substitution); `str_match_all`, `str_extract_all`, and `regmatches/gregexpr` combo.

I like @kohske's regex, which looks behind for an open parenthesis `?<=\\(`, looks ahead for a closing parenthesis `?=\\)`, and grabs everything in the middle (lazily) `.+?`, in other words `(?<=\\().+?(?=\\))`

Using the same  regex:

`str_match_all` returns the answer as a **matrix**.

```
str_match_all(j, "(?<=\\().+?(?=\\))")

     [,1]    
[1,] "wonder"
[2,] "groan" 
[3,] "Laugh" 

# Subset the matrix like this....

str_match_all(j, "(?<=\\().+?(?=\\))")[[1]][,1]
[1] "wonder" "groan"  "Laugh"
```

`str_extract_all` returns the answer as a **list**.

```
str_extract_all(j,  "(?<=\\().+?(?=\\))")
[[1]]
[1] "wonder" "groan"  "Laugh" 

#Subset the list...
str_extract_all(j,  "(?<=\\().+?(?=\\))")[[1]]
[1] "wonder" "groan"  "Laugh"
```

`regmatches/gregexpr` also returns the answer as a **list**. Since this is a base R option, some people prefer it. Note the recommended `perl = TRUE`.

```
regmatches(j, gregexpr( "(?<=\\().+?(?=\\))", j, perl = T))
[[1]]
[1] "wonder" "groan"  "Laugh" 

#Subset the list...
regmatches(j, gregexpr( "(?<=\\().+?(?=\\))", j, perl = T))[[1]]
[1] "wonder" "groan"  "Laugh"
```

Hopefully, the SO community will correct/edit this answer if I've mischaracterized the most popular options.

Answer (score 7):

Using [rex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/index.html) may make this type of task a little simpler.

```
matches <- re_matches(j,
  rex(
    "(",
    capture(name = "text", except_any_of(")")),
    ")"),
  global = TRUE)

matches[[1]]$text
#>[1] "wonder" "groan"  "Laugh"
```