# Extract numbers between brackets within a string

Tags: regex, r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract info inside all parenthesis in R (regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613237/extract-info-inside-all-parenthesis-in-r-regex)

I inported data from excel and one cell consists of these long strings that contain number and letters, is there a way to extract only the numbers from that string and store it in a new variable? Unfortunately, some of the entries have two sets of brackets and I would only want the second one? Could I use grep for that?

the strings look more or less like this, the length of the strings vary however:

```
"East Kootenay C (5901035) RDA 01011"
```

or like this:

```
"Thompson-Nicola J (Copper Desert Country) (5933039) RDA 02020"
```

All I want from this is `5901035` and `5933039`

Any hints and help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible for there to be two instances of numbers-in-brackets in the same line? For example, `"East Kootenay C (5901035) (5933039) RDA 01011"`

Answer (score 10):

There are many possible regular expressions to do this.  Here is one:

```
x=c("East Kootenay C (5901035) RDA 01011","Thompson-Nicola J (Copper Desert Country) (5933039) RDA 02020")

> gsub('.+\\(([0-9]+)\\).+?$', '\\1', x)
[1] "5901035" "5933039"
```

Lets break down the syntax of that first expression `'.+\\(([0-9]+)\\).+'`

- `.+` one or more of anything
- `\\(` parentheses are special characters in a regular expression, so if I want to represent the actual thing `(` I need to escape it with a `\`.  I have to escape it again for R (hence the two `\`s).
- `([0-9]+)` I mentioned special characters, here I use two.  the first is the parentheses which indicate a group I want to keep.  The second `[` and `]` surround groups of things. see `?regex` for more information.
- `?$` The final piece assures that I am grabbing the LAST set of numbers in parens as noted in the comments.

I could also use `*` instead of `.` which would mean 0 or more rather than one or more i in case your paren string comes at the beginning or end of a string.

The second piece of the `gsub` is what I am replacing the first portion with.  I used: `\\1`.  This says use group 1 (the stuff inside the `( )` from above. I need to escape it twice again, once for the regex and once for R.

Clear as mud to be sure! Enjoy your data munging project!

Comment: Nicely done with the regexplanation!

Comment: I'd add two characters to your regex to make sure that OP is grabbing the last number-in-bracket: `gsub('.+\\(([0-9]+)\\).+?$', '\\1', x)`. Perhaps swap out `+` and put in `*` depending on needs as well.

Comment: @BlueMagister good call. edited accordingly

Answer (score 3):

Here is a gsubfn solution:

```
library(gsubfn)

strapplyc(x, "[(](\\d+)[)]", simplify = TRUE)
```

`[(]` matches an open paren, `(\\d+)` matches a string of digits creating a back-reference owing to the parens around it and finally `[)]` matches a close paren.   The back-reference is returned.