# Regex for extracting 3 digits numbers between brackets

Tags: java, regex

My string is:

```
Frequency/FA ID VerifiedFA0 FAID5(125)/FA1 FAID7(175)/FA2 FAID1(476)
```

The regex I'm trying to create should extract these numbers:

```
125, 175, 476
```

I did it by looking at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735503/extract-numbers-between-brackets-within-a-string) but there must be a better one.

```
myString.replaceAll(".+\\(([0-9]+)\\).+\\(([0-9]+)\\).+\\(([0-9]+)\\).*","$1,$2,$3")
```

Comment: What is wrong with the solution you have? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Here is a java regex testing site: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html

Comment: @Till Helge Helwig, I'm trying to find better one because i will need it soon for similar tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:

```
String s = "Frequency/FA ID VerifiedFA0 FAID5(125)/FA1 FAID7(175)/FA2 FAID1(476)";
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("\\(\\d+\\)");
Matcher match = patt.matcher(s);
while(match.find()){
    System.out.println(match.group());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than `replacing` everything that you don't need, you can use [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class, to extract what you need.

The regex pattern to extract numbers between brackets would be: -

```
\(\d+\)
```

`+` quantifier is used to match `1 or more` repetition of digits. If you want to match just `3` digits, then you can use `{3}` quantifier with `\d`: - `\(\d{3}\)`.

You can apply this regex pattern with [`Matcher#find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method to get all the numbers from that string. I leave the task of implementation to you.

Answer (score 1):

Slight change:

This finds exactly 3 digits inside of parentheses:  ((\d\d\d))

The actual string value (in java) is: `"(\\(\\d\\d\\d\\))"`

Test on the [Java RegEx Test page](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html)