# How do I extract numbers only with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string '[123456] Filename123' and I want to get only the numbers inside [].

Input: `[123456] Filename123`, Output: `['123456']`, I want `123456`

My code:

```
from plexapi.server import PlexServer
import re
authType = 1

def getNumbers(str):
    str = re.findall(r'[0-9].....', str)
    return str

if authType == 1:
    baseurl = 'http://localhost:32400'
    token = 'token'
    plex = PlexServer(baseurl, token)

pics = plex.library.section('Pictures')
print(pics.search())

for name in pics.search():
    print(name.title)
    print(getNumbers(name.title))
```

Comment: Why don't you want `123` also?

Comment: You should provide more examples to know the cornercases. For example, does the strings always start with `[`? Are the numbers always between `[` and `]`? Do we need to skip finding numbers once we already found on in the string?

Comment: Already kinda discussed here, check it out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591258/regex-for-extracting-3-digits-numbers-between-brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `re.search` with the following pattern:

```
import re
s =  '[123456] Filename123' 
re.search(r'\[(\d+)\]', s).group(1)
# '123456'
```

Comment: @Slimey if there is a case where the square bracket like [01 23], above code won't work