# R Extract number from string

Tags: r, string, numeric, gsub

I have been trying to get this right. What I want to do is extract a year from a string. The string looks like this for example:

`Toy Story (1995)`

Or it could look like this

`Twelve Monkeys (a.k.a. 12 Monkeys) (1995)`

To extract the numbers, I currently use

`year = gsub("(?<=\\()[^()]*(?=\\))(*SKIP)(*F)|.", "", x, perl=T)`

Now, this would work in most cases, where the first one is used, but in the list the second one is also used.

```
[1] 1995
[2] a.k.a. 12 Monkeys1995
```

So obviously I do not want the string but only the year, how do I get this?

Comment: Use just `sub(".*\\((\\d{4})\\).*", "\\1", x)`

Comment: Have a look at the `gsubfn` suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735503/extract-numbers-between-brackets-within-a-string) - `library(gsubfn); strapplyc(x, "[(](\\d+)[)]", simplify = TRUE)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract(x, "(?<=\\()[0-9]+(?=\\))"))
#[1] 1995 1995
```

#### data

```
x <-  c("Toy Story (1995)", "Twelve Monkeys (a.k.a. 12 Monkeys) (1995)")
```

Comment: as number, not string, lol.... `as.numeric(str_extract(x, "(?<=\\()[0-9]+(?=\\))"))`   very precise  @akrun. good one.

Comment: @ManojKumar Yes, I forgot to wrap with `as.numeric`

Answer (score 2):

```
stringi::stri_match_last_regex(x, "\\(([[:digit:]]+)\\)")[,2]
```

Escaping the parens is still a pain, but it's a far more readable regex IMO.

Answer (score 0):

If the years are always located at the end of each string circled by parentheses, you could do this in base R:

```
as.numeric(gsub("\\(|\\)", "", substr(x, nchar(x)-5,nchar(x))))
#[1] 1995 1995
```

Use `trimws(x)` beforehand in case there might be any head or tail spaces.