# Sort data in a data frame according to the numbers in a factor

Tags: r

I have several data frames, which I bound to a final containing two variables : "Label" and "Mean".

The label it is is this format:

```
>                                               Label       Mean
>1       C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (10) 18.97021 
>2       C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (11) 16.40476
>3       C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (12) 24.79132
>4       C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (13) 20.95391
>5       C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (14) 19.67626
>6       C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (15) 28.93776
```

I would like to organize the data according to the number in Label, to something like this:

```
>                                              Label       Mean
>1       C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (1) 18.97021
>2       C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (2) 16.40476
>3       C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (3) 24.79132
>4       C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (4) 20.95391
>5       C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (5) 19.67626
>6       C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (6) 28.93776
```

There is any advise to accomplish such thing? 
Thank you

Comment: you should probably start by extracting the numbers in the brackets using Regular Expressions. Afterwards, `order` would be the way to go.

Comment: And when you break the problem into chunks you often find that each already has a solution. F.ex. [extracting a number between brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735503/extract-numbers-between-brackets-within-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `mixedorder` from `gtools`:

```
df[gtools::mixedorder(df$Label),]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, it worked very well =)

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution extracting the number inside "()" using strsplit:

Example Input data:

```
df<-data.frame(Label=c("C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (12)",
                        "C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (11)",
                        "C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (10)"),
                Mean=c(1,2,3))

df
                                           Label Mean
1 C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (12)    1
2 C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (11)    2
3 C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (10)    3
```

Ordering:

```
df[order(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Label),split="(",fixed=T),"[",2)),split=")")))),]
                                           Label Mean
3 C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (10)    3
2 C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (11)    2
1 C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (12)    1
```

Comment: you should adjust the formatting :), nice one-liner though

Answer (score 1):

I first create a new variable getting all numerics after the first parenthesis, excluding it. then I order the data frame

```
library(stringr)

df$label_id = as.numeric(str_exctract(df$label, '(?<=\\()\\d+'))
df = df[order(label_id),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` approach to order by `Label` and mutate `Label`

```
library(magrittr)
ans <- df %>%
        dplyr::arrange(as.numeric(gsub(".*\\((\\d+)\\)$", "\\1", Label))) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(Label = paste0(gsub("(.*)\\(\\d+\\)$", "\\1", Label), "(", row_number(), ")"))

                                          # Label     Mean
# 1 C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (1) 18.97021
# 2 C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (2) 16.40476
# 3 C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (3) 24.79132
# 4 C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (4) 20.95391
# 5 C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (5) 19.67626
# 6 C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (6) 28.93776
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text="Label,Mean
C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (10),18.97021 
C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (11),16.40476
C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (12),24.79132
C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (13),20.95391
C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (14),19.67626
C2-Concatenated Stacks-1:c:2/3 - MDAMB231 (15),28.93776", header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```