# regex to pickout some text between parenthesis

Tags: regex, r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract info inside all parenthesis in R (regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613237/extract-info-inside-all-parenthesis-in-r-regex)

I have a string

df

```
Peoplesoft(id-1290)
```

I like to capture characters between the parentesis, for example. I like to get id-1290 from the above example.

I used this:

```
x <- regexpr("\\((.*)\\)", df)
```

this is giving me numbers like

```
[1] 10
```

Is there an easy way to grab text between parentesis using regex in R?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I prefer to use `gsub()` for this:

```
gsub(".*\\((.*)\\).*", "\\1", df)
[1] "id-1290"
```

---

The regex works like this:

- Find text inside the parentheses - not your real parentheses, but my extra set of parentheses, i.e. `(.*)`
- Return this as a back-reference, `\\1`

In other words, substitute all text in the string with the back reference

---

If you want to use `regexp` rather than `gsub`, then do this:

```
x <- regexpr("\\((.*)\\)", df)
x

[1] 11
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 9
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

This returns a value of 11, i.e. the starting position of the found expression. And note the attribute `match.length` that indicates how many characters were matched.

You can extract this with `attr`:

```
attr(x, "match.length")
[1] 9
```

And then use `substring` to extract the characters:

```
substring(df, x+1, x+attr(x, "match.length")-2)
[1] "id-1290"
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a slightly different way, using lookbehind/ahead:

```
df <- "Peoplesoft(id-1290)"
regmatches(df,gregexpr("(?<=\\().*?(?=\\))", df, perl=TRUE))
```

Difference with Andrie's answer is that this also works to extract multiple strings in brackets. e.g.:

```
df <- "Peoplesoft(id-1290) blabla (foo)"
regmatches(df,gregexpr("(?<=\\().*?(?=\\))", df, perl=TRUE))
```

Gives:

```
[[1]]
[1] "id-1290" "foo"
```