# Regular expression in R - extract only match

Tags: r, regex

My strings look like as follows:

```
crb_gdp_g_100000_16_16_ftv_all.txt
crb_gdp_g_100000_16_20_fweo2_all.txt
crb_gdp_g_100000_4_40_fweo2_galt_1.txt
```

I only want to extract the part between f and the following underscore (in these three cases "tv", "weo2" and "weo2").

My regular expression is:

```
regex.f = "_f([[:alnum:]]+)_"
```

There is no string with more than one part matching the pattern. Why does the following command not work?

```
sub(regex.f, "\\1", "crb_gdp_g_100000_16_16_ftv_all.txt")
```

The command only removes "_f" from the string and returns the remaining string.

Comment: Are you sure you need `weo` and not `weo2`? What if there is `_fw2eo2_`?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I need weo2.

Comment: Can there be more than one occurrence? `_ftv_fwe4_`? The answers below will yield different results in these cases.

Comment: Your  `sub` does not work because you are *replacing*, but your regex does not match the *whole* string. You need to match the whole string to remove it, and only keep what you need using backreferences to the capturing groups inside the string replacement pattern.

Comment: No, only exactly one occurrence.

Comment: But shouldn't I only get the match, since I put it in parentheses?

Comment: That is why Benjamin's approach is more natural in this case, when you need to *match*. It is not Python where you can use `re.findall` and it will fetch you only the capturing group value. `sub` advantage is that it keeps the value unmodified if the regex does not match while `regmatches` will just find no match.

Answer (score 4):

Can easily be achived with `qdapRegex`

```
df <- c("crb_gdp_g_100000_16_16_ftv_all.txt", 
"crb_gdp_g_100000_16_20_fweo2_all.txt", 
"crb_gdp_g_100000_4_40_fweo2_galt_1.txt")

library(qdapRegex)
rm_between(df, "_f", "_", extract=TRUE)
```

Comment: The initial boundary is `_f`

Answer (score 3):

We can use `sub` extract the strings by matching the character`f` followed by one or more characters that are not an underscore or numbers (`[^_0-9]+`), capture as a group (`(...)`), followed by 0 or more numbers (`\\d*`) followed by an `_` and other characters.  Replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub(".*_f([^_0-9]+)\\d*_.*", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "tv"  "weo" "weo"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("crb_gdp_g_100000_16_16_ftv_all.txt", 
    "crb_gdp_g_100000_16_20_fweo2_all.xml",
     "crb_gdp_g_100000_4_40_fweo2_galt_1.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks, works for all cases. But why does my approach not work? Where's my mistake?

Comment: @tho_mi what your approach does is find, for example `ftv_` and replace it with `tv`.  @akrun is looking for any string that ends in an `f`, followed by `tv`, followed by any string that starts with a `_`, and replaces it with `tv`.  The difference is that you haven't told `sub` what to do with the leading and trailing characters, so it leaves them in tact.

Comment: I see. I thought using parantheses only returns the stuff between them, discarding the rest.

Answer (score 3):

My usual regex for extracting the text between two characters comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13499594/1017276, which specifically looks at extracting text between parentheses.  This approach only changes the parentheses to `f` and `_`.

```
x <- c("crb_gdp_g_100000_16_16_ftv_all.txt",
       "crb_gdp_g_100000_16_20_fweo2_all.xml",
       "crb_gdp_g_100000_4_40_fweo2_galt_1.txt",
       "crb_gdp_g_100000_20_tbf_16_nqa_8_flin_galt_2.xml")

regmatches(x,gregexpr("(?<=_f).*?(?=_)", x, perl=TRUE))
```

Or with the `stringr` package.

```
library(stringr)

str_extract(x, "(?<=_f).*?(?=_)")
```

*edited to start the match on* `_f` *instead of* `f`.

#### NOTE

akrun's answer runs a few milliseconds faster than the `stringr` approach, and about ten times faster than the `base` approach.  The `base` approach clocks in at about 100 milliseconds for a character vector of 10,000 elements.

Comment: Sorry, my examples were bad (/insufficient) and your code doesn't work for my third example.

Comment: @tho_mi I think [it works for all cases](https://regex101.com/r/rvpx9g/1).

Comment: Yes, (now?) it works for all cases, but in some cases it returns an empty string first.

Comment: @Benjamin, why does the approach of akrun work but mine doesn't?

Comment: @tho_mi I'd be interested in a case where you are getting the empty string first. My first thought on such a case is that no match was found.

Comment: In case of the following string I get an empty string first, followed by "lin": crb_gdp_g_100000_20_tbf_16_nqa_8_flin_galt_2.xml

Comment: @tho_mi [You said there is always a single occurrence.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350677/regular-expression-in-r-extract-only-match#comment77662870_45350677) So, you want to only get the last one? In `crb_gdp_g_100000_20_tbf_16_nqa_8_flin_galt_2.xml`, there is `f_` and `_flin_`.

Comment: Does that matter? The first case doesn't begin with an underscore?

Comment: Ok, so you need `"(?<=_f).*?(?=_)"` then

Comment: Ah, yes. I now use my example, just with ".*" at the beginning and the end. This way everything works fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

update: capture match using `str_match`

```
library(stringr)  
m <- str_match("crb_gdp_g_100000_16_20_fweo2_all.txt", "_f([[:alnum:]]+)_")
print(m[[2]])
# weo2
```

your regex not work because missing starting and ending match `.*` and use `\w` for shorthand `[:alnum:]`

```
sub(".*_f(\\w+?)_.*", "\\1", "crb_gdp_g_100000_16_20_fweo2_all.txt")
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! That means by default sub tries to match the whole string and not just substrings?

Comment: I think you have misunderstanding, `sub` is for replacing string, and to extract match you need `regmatches`

Comment: Ok, I see. Does that also mean that the parantheses don't work in case of regmatches? Using regmatches with the regular expression from my code I get things like "_fweo2_"? Is this conclusion correct?

Comment: not correct, use `str_match` to capture group, see updated answer, it using your regex.

Comment: @tho_mi You can use `regmatches` together with `regexec` to return captured subexpressions, but the process is a bit more cumbersome. Here, `regmatches("crb_gdp_g_100000_16_20_fweo2_all.txt", regexec("_f([[:alnum:]]+)_", "crb_gdp_g_100000_16_20_fweo2_all.txt"))[[c(1, 2)]]` will return the same result as the `str_match` call above.

Answer (score 1):

We could use the package *unglue* :

```r
library(unglue)
txt <- c("crb_gdp_g_100000_16_16_ftv_all.txt", 
       "crb_gdp_g_100000_16_20_fweo2_all.txt", 
       "crb_gdp_g_100000_4_40_fweo2_galt_1.txt")

pattern <-
  "crb_gdp_g_100000_{=\\d+}_{=\\d+}_f{x}_{=.+?}.txt"
unglue_vec(txt,pattern)
#> [1] "tv"   "weo2" "weo2"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>