# capture string between special characters

Tags: r, regex

I have this string:

```
node<-c("Current CPU load - UAT_jvm1[mainnetwork-cmod_svc_group_mem1]@tt11")
```

I need to capture this text from it, from "- " til the "@" sign.

```
UAT_jvm1[mainnetwork-cmod_svc_group_mem1]
```

I've tried this:

```
str_match(node, ".*\\-+s(.*?)@.*")[,2]
```

any ideas?

Comment: `regmatches(node,gregexpr("(?<=-\\s).*?(?=@)", node, perl=TRUE))`

Comment: You made a typo, you should have written it as `".*-\\s(.*?)@.*"`, but it is not an efficient pattern.

Comment: Missed the space. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gsub` to match zero or more characters until a `-` followed by space or `|` the `@` followed by other characters and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
gsub(".*-\\s|@.*", "", node)
#[1] "UAT_jvm1[mainnetwork-cmod_svc_group_mem1]"
```

---

Or if we are using `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(node, "(?<=-\\s)[^@]+")
#[1] "UAT_jvm1[mainnetwork-cmod_svc_group_mem1]"
```

#### data

```
node <- c("Current CPU load - UAT_jvm1[mainnetwork-cmod_svc_group_mem1]@tt11")
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas here,

**1)** Using `regmatches` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13499594/5635580), i.e

```
regmatches(node,gregexpr("(?<=-\\s).*?(?=@)", node, perl=TRUE))
```

**2)** Using the fun function `word` from `stringr`, i.e.

```
stringr::word(node, 2, sep = ' - |@')
```

Both resulting in

> ```
> [1] "UAT_jvm1[mainnetwork-cmod_svc_group_mem1]"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some approaches.  No packages are used.

**1) sub** Match everything to the minus space and then capture everything up to but not including the @:

```
sub(".*- (.*)@.*", "\\1", node)
## [1] "UAT_jvm1[mainnetwork-cmod_svc_group_mem1]"
```

**2) sub/read.table** Replace the first - with an @ and then read the string picking out the second field.

```
read.table(text = sub("-", "@", node), sep = "@", as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)[[2]]
## [1] "UAT_jvm1[mainnetwork-cmod_svc_group_mem1]"
```

**3) gsub**  Remove everything up to the minus space and everything from @ onwards:

```
gsub("^.*- |@.*", "", node)
## [1] "UAT_jvm1[mainnetwork-cmod_svc_group_mem1]"
```