# How to split a string on single quotes

Tags: r

I'm trying to split a string on single quotes.

```
str <- "Hello World, I'm splitting this string on 'Single Quotes'"
test <- strsplit(str , "'")
```

> "Hello World, I'm splitting this string on " "Single Quotes"

I got both values above, but I want only the value `Single Quotes`. I know this is a basic question, but I'm new to R programming and trying to learn. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `strsplit(str , "'")[[1]][2]` ? or If you want regex, `regmatches(str, gregexpr("(?<=').*?(?=')", str, perl = TRUE))`

Comment: Adapting a solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13498914/1017276); `gsub(".*\\'(.*)\\'.*", "\\1", str)`

Comment: Thanks, i tried the above line of code, but the problem is when i include any other string between two single quotes, those string also present in the result. Ex: "Single quotes" "BLA BLA" "Second Single quotes"

Comment: Please include all cases in your question