# Import exponential values as numeric in R

Tags: r, import

I have to import many datasets automatically with the first column being a name, so a character vector, and the second column being a numeric vector, so I was using these specifications with read.table: colClasses = c("character", "numeric").

This works great if I have a dataframe saved in a df_file like this:

```
df<- data.frame(V1=c("s1","s2","s3","s4"), V2=c("1e-04","1e-04","1e-04","1e-04")

read.table(df_file, header = FALSE,  comment.char="", colClasses = c("character", "numeric"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The problem is in some cases I have dataframes with numeric values in the form of exponential in the second column, and in these cases the import does not work since it does not recognise the column as numeric (or it imports as "character" if I don't specify the colClasses), so my question is: 
how can I specify a column to be imported as numeric even when the values are exponential?

For example:

```
df<- data.frame(V1=c("s1","s2","s3","s4"), V2=c("10^(-4)","10^(-4)","10^(-4)","10^(-4)"))
```

I want all the exponential values to be imported as numeric, but even when I try to change from character to numeric after they are imported I get all "NA" (as.numeric(as.character(df$V2)) "Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion ")

I have tried to use "real" or "complex" with colClasses too but it still imports the exponentials as character.

Please help,
thank you!

Comment: try something like: `as.numeric(gsub("0\\^", "e", gsub("[()]", "", df$V2)))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract info inside all parenthesis in R (regex)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613237/extract-info-inside-all-parenthesis-in-r-regex)

Comment: Hi Arun, thank you. So I guess there isn't an "easy way out"? Meaning, if I want to do this do I have to first import all the datasets with the second column "as.character" and then do this only if the columns have an exponential term?

Comment: @user2337032, you can use `readLines` instead. I've posted an answer.

Comment: Thank you Arun your function works too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that the form your exponentials are written in doesn't match the R style. If you read them in as character vectors you can convert them to exponentials if you know they all are exponentials. Use gsub to strip out the "10^(" and the ")", leaving you with the "-4", convert to numeric, then convert back to an exponential. Might not be the fastest way, but it works.

From your example:

```
 df<- data.frame(V1=c("s1","s2","s3","s4"), V2=c("10^(-4)","10^(-4)","10^(-4)","10^(-4)"))
 df$V2 <- 10^(as.numeric(gsub("10\\^\\(|\\)", "", df$V2)))
 df
#  V1    V2
#1 s1 1e-04
#2 s2 1e-04
#3 s3 1e-04
#4 s4 1e-04
```

Whats happening in detail: `gsub("10\\^\\(|\\)", "", df$V2)` is substituting 10^( and ) with an empty string (you need to escape the carat and the parentheses), `as.numeric()` is converting your -4 string into the number -4, then you're just running 10^ on each element of the numeric vector you just made.

Comment: Thank you, this works. I just first imported as character and grepped to check if there was the "^", then used your code. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

If you read in your `data.frame` with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, the column in question should come in as a character vector, in which case you can simply do:

```
transform(df, V2=eval(parse(text=V2)))
```

Comment: This is much simpler! Just one question, how would I use this if I had colnames (so header=TRUE) and wanted to substitute that second column? This gives me an error: df[,2] <- transform(df, V2=eval(parse(text=df[,2]))). Thank you!!

Comment: Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , 2, value = list(V1 = c("s1",  :
  provided 2 variables to replace 1 variables

Comment: can you post the output of `dput(head(df, 5))`?

Comment: yes sure, > dput(head(df, 5))
structure(list(V1 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("s1", "s2", "s3", 
"s4"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "10^(-4)", class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Your V2 column as a factor. You'll either have to convert to character, or read it in again with `as.is=TRUE`. The reason you're getting the error is because you want `df <- transform(df, V2=eval(parse(text=as.character(V2))))`, not `df[, 2] <- ...`

Comment: Sorry… Ths is perfect, simple and elegant solution. I wish I could give you a check too..I used a combination of all these answers, i.e. I checked if there were these characters with readLines, then if there were I imported the data as characters and used your function to convert. Thank you to all!!

Comment: that's ok, maybe next time ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `readLines` to first load in the data and do all the operations required and then use `read.table` with `textConnection` as follows:

```
tt <- readLines("~/tmp.txt")
tt <- gsub("10\\^\\((.*)\\)$", "1e\\1", tt)
read.table(textConnection(tt), sep="\t", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  V1    V2
1 s1 1e-04
2 s2 1e-04
3 s3 1e-04
4 s4 1e-04
```

Comment: This could be faster actually than reading all of the file first and it is better for me since my files are huge! Thank you!

Comment: Still, I think there is a problem with re-importing as a dataframe with separate columns: tt <- readLines("~/tmp.txt"); if(all(grep("10\\^\\((.*)\\)$", tt))) {tt <- gsub("10\\^\\((.*)\\)$", "1e\\1", tt)}; df <- read.table(textConnection(tt), sep="\t", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Comment: that's because you are using `\(` instead of `\\(` and `\)` instead of `\\)`. You should escape twice.