# Extract text in parentheses in R

Tags: r, string, text, vector, stringr

Two related questions. I have vectors of text data such as

```
"a(b)jk(p)"  "ipq"  "e(ijkl)"
```

and want to easily separate it into a vector containing the text OUTSIDE the parentheses:

```
"ajk"  "ipq"  "e"
```

and a vector containing the text INSIDE the parentheses:

```
"bp"   ""  "ijkl"
```

Is there any easy way to do this? An added difficulty is that these can get quite large and have a large (unlimited) number of parentheses. Thus, I can't simply grab text "pre/post" the parentheses and need a smarter solution.

Comment: This post might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613237/extract-info-inside-all-parenthesis-in-r-regex

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Text outside the parenthesis**

```
> x <- c("a(b)jk(p)"  ,"ipq" , "e(ijkl)")
> gsub("\\([^()]*\\)", "", x)
[1] "ajk" "ipq" "e"
```

**Text inside the parenthesis**

```
> x <- c("a(b)jk(p)"  ,"ipq" , "e(ijkl)")
> gsub("(?<=\\()[^()]*(?=\\))(*SKIP)(*F)|.", "", x, perl=T)
[1] "bp"   ""     "ijkl"
```

The `(?<=\\()[^()]*(?=\\))` matches all the characters which are present inside the brackets and then the following `(*SKIP)(*F)` makes the match to fail. Now it tries to execute the pattern which was just after to `|` symbol against the remaining string. So the dot `.` matches all the characters which are not already skipped. Replacing all the matched characters with an empty string will give only the text present inside the rackets.

```
> gsub("\\(([^()]*)\\)|.", "\\1", x, perl=T)
[1] "bp"   ""     "ijkl"
```

This regex would capture all the characters which are present inside the brackets and matches all the other characters. `|.` or part helps to match all the remaining characters other than the captured ones. So by replacing all the characters with the chars present inside the group index 1 will give you the desired output.

Comment: I would assume it accidental as a downvote makes no sense.  The extraction was cool because you extracted and put together without `paste`ing.  +1

Comment: @TylerRinker yep, someone got angry with me and so he put 4 downvotes on my answer which has a min score of 1. My bad.

Comment: @TylerRinker could you provide the link to qdapRegex package?

Comment: To the first comment "petty" :-(  To the second...Sure https://github.com/trinker/qdapRegex  I linked in my answer too.  It's a CRAN package as well.

Comment: @TylerRinker qdapRegex was definitely a well put together package.

Answer (score 7):

The `rm_round` function in the [**qdapRegex** package](https://github.com/trinker/qdapRegex) I maintain was born to do this:

First we'll get and load the package via **pacman**

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(qdapRegex)
```

**## Then we can use it to remove and extract the parts you want**:

```
x <-c("a(b)jk(p)", "ipq", "e(ijkl)")

rm_round(x)

## [1] "ajk" "ipq" "e" 

rm_round(x, extract=TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "b" "p"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] NA
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "ijkl"
```

To condense `b` and `p` use:

```
sapply(rm_round(x, extract=TRUE), paste, collapse="")

## [1] "bp"   "NA"   "ijkl"
```

Comment: `regmatches(x,gregexpr("(?<=\\().+?(?=\\))",x,perl=TRUE))` for a `regmatches` version in base, with `regmatches(x,gregexpr("(?<=\\)|^).+?(?=\\(|$)",x,perl=TRUE))` for the reverse.

Comment: @thelatemail That deserves its own answer.