# Extract info inside parenthesis in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have some rows, some have parenthesis and some don't. Like `ABC(DEF)` and `ABC`. I want to extract info from parenthesis:

- ABC(DEF) -> DEF
- ABC -> NA

I wrote

```
gsub(".*\\((.*)\\).*", "\\1",X).
```

It works good for ABC(DEF), but output "ABC" when there is not parenthesis.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/pq2NmX

Comment: You can also use stringr `str_match(X, "\\(([^()]*)\\)")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to get `ABC` when using `sub` with your regex, you need to add an alternative that would match all the non-empty string and remove it.

```
X <- c("ABC(DEF)", "ABC")
sub(".*(?:\\((.*)\\)).*|.*", "\\1",X)
                       ^^^
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/pq2NmX).

Note you do not have to use `gsub`, you only need one replacement to be performed, so a `sub` will do.

Also, a *stringr* `str_match` would also be handy for this task:

```
str_match(X, "\\((.*)\\)")
```

or

```
str_match(X, "\\(([^()]*)\\)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using string_extract() will work.

```
library(stringr) 

df$`new column` <- str_extract(df$`existing column`,  "(?<=\\().+?(?=\\))")
```

This creates a new column of any text inside parentheses of an existing column. If there is no parentheses in the column, it will fill in NA.

The inspiration for my answer comes from [this answer on the original question about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51913050/11099141)