# Extract string between [ and ] only if + is between [ and ]

Tags: r, regex

I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find it.

The closest I've found so far is:

[Extract info inside all parenthesis in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8613332/1017276)

I am wanting to extract from a string any match that starts with a `[`, ends with a `]`, and has a `+` plus between those brackets.  The regular expression I've put together based on a previous answer is a little too greedy.

```
library(magrittr)

str <- "[a] , [a + b] + [b] , [b - q] , [d - e + f]"

gregexpr(pattern = "(?=\\[).*?[+].*?(?<=\\])",
         text = str,
         perl = TRUE) %>%
  regmatches(x = str,
             m = .)
```

This returns

```
[[1]]
[1] "[a] , [a + b]"               "[b] , [b - q] , [d - e + f]"
```

where what I want is

```
[[1]]
[1] "[a + b]"               "[d - e + f]"
```

Comment: What do you want it to return in cases like "[a - [b + c]]" or "[a + [b - c]] , [a]"?

Comment: I hadn't thought about nesting, but Tot's answer is sufficient for my need to disallow `+` between brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
\\[[^]+]+[+][^]]+\\]
```

Comment: That does is.  And looks so much less intimidating.