# regex: get text between two words (in R)

Tags: r, regex

I have a text document and I'm trying to get the text between the words "abstract" and "keywords" (in R). This is the code I'm using:

```
gsub(".*abstract\\s*|keywords.*", "\\1", string)
```

However, this didn't work because somewhere else in the text the word "abstract" occurred so I made it non-greedy like this (added ? in front of abstract)

```
gsub(".*?abstract\\s*|keywords.*", "\\1", string)
```

But for some reason it now takes the text between "abstract" and "keywords" (which is what I want), but ALSO the text starting from the second "abstract" appearing in the text, all the way to the end.
Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract info inside all parenthesis in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613237/extract-info-inside-all-parenthesis-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it doesn't look like you are capturing anything in your search term, you just need some `()`'s in there to actually grab something so `\\1` will return your target :

```
words <- c("these are some different abstract words that might be between keywords or they might just be bounded by abstract ideas")
gsub(".* abstract (.*) keywords.*", "\\1", words)
[1] "words that might be between"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer! To be honest, I'm not good at regex, I just found the command by searching it on Google. One more question though, I used the exact same command to get text between "abstract" and "introduction" and for some reason that one does work. Do you know why? Here is the code: gsub(".*abstract\\s*|introduction.*", "", words)

Comment: first here is my favorite cheat sheet: https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/ (I use that thing A LOT, because regex is hard)

Comment: Yes I know, but my question was why that piece of code I posted works (believe it or not, but it does actually work for the introduction part and not for the keywords part, which is why I'm confused). Thanks again!

Comment: ooooh i see, i can't tell you for certain without seeing the actual text you are working with, likely what happened is by subbing both of your search terms with empty strings (`\\1` was really `""`, since nothing was being caught), all you were left with was your target, but like you saw later that strategy isn't always going to give you words between your "boundaries"

Answer (score 3):

I think this should give you what you are looking for:

```
regmatches(string, gregexpr("(?<=abstract).*(?=keywords)", string, perl = TRUE))
```

What it does:

- `(?<=abstract)` use the "look ahead" capabilities to find things after the word "abstract"
- `.*` match any number of keywords
- `(?=keywords)` use the "look behind" for find things before the word "keywords"
- `gregexpr` looks for the given regular expression in `string`
- `perl = TRUE` allows for the "look ahead" and "look behind" functionality
- `regmatches` pulls out the matching piece of the string using the regular expression.