# Extract string between third set of parentheses

Tags: r, regex, string

I wish to extract the portion of a `string` between the third set of parentheses,  preferably using base `R`.  Here is an example data set:

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
     my.num                              my.string                                  my.cov
        1    Abc(~1)Fgf(~-1+e2:cp)Bca(~-1+g1+g2:ti+g2:cfi+g2:pp+g2:cp)q(~-1+re:se)    10
        2    Abc(~1)Fgf(~-1+e1:e2:fi)Bca(~-1+g1+g2:ti+g2:pr+g2:ts+g2:cfi)q(~1)        20
        3    Abc(~1)Fgf(~1)Bca(~-1+g1+g2+g2:cp)q(~-1+re:se)                           15
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
my.data
```

Either of these two results would be helpful:

```
desired.result1 <- read.table(text = '
     my.num                     my.string            my.cov
        1    Bca(~-1+g1+g2:ti+g2:cfi+g2:pp+g2:cp)      10
        2    Bca(~-1+g1+g2:ti+g2:pr+g2:ts+g2:cfi)      20
        3    Bca(~-1+g1+g2+g2:cp)                      15
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
desired.result1

desired.result2 <- read.table(text = '
     my.num                     my.string       my.cov
        1    ~-1+g1+g2:ti+g2:cfi+g2:pp+g2:cp      10
        2    ~-1+g1+g2:ti+g2:pr+g2:ts+g2:cfi      20
        3    ~-1+g1+g2+g2:cp                      15
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
desired.result2
```

I am so rusty on `regex` I am not even sure where to begin and could not locate a similar question on the internet.  Thank you for any advice or assistance.

Comment: split on "(", get the third one, tidy up.

Comment: Can there be nested parentheses?

Comment: [This could be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613237/extract-info-inside-all-parenthesis-in-r)

Comment: What about the spacing to my.cov column?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No.

Comment: @bobblebubble The spacing between columns does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Expression:

```
sub(".*?\\(.*?\\).*?\\(.*?\\)(.*?\\(.*?\\)).*", "\\1", my.data$my.string)
[1] "Bca(~-1+g1+g2:ti+g2:cfi+g2:pp+g2:cp)" "Bca(~-1+g1+g2:ti+g2:pr+g2:ts+g2:cfi)"
[3] "Bca(~-1+g1+g2+g2:cp)"
```

Second Expression:

```
sub(".*?\\(.*?\\).*?\\(.*?\\).*?\\((.*?)\\).*", "\\1", my.data$my.string)
[1] "~-1+g1+g2:ti+g2:cfi+g2:pp+g2:cp" "~-1+g1+g2:ti+g2:pr+g2:ts+g2:cfi" "~-1+g1+g2+g2:cp"
```

Answer (score 4):

Using strsplit:

```
sapply(strsplit(my.data$my.string, split = "(", fixed = TRUE), function(i){
  strsplit(i[4], split = ")", fixed = TRUE)[[1]][1]})

# [1] "~-1+g1+g2:ti+g2:cfi+g2:pp+g2:cp" "~-1+g1+g2:ti+g2:pr+g2:ts+g2:cfi" "~-1+g1+g2+g2:cp"
```

Comment: or this `paste0(sapply(strsplit(my.data$my.string, '\\)'), '[', 3), ')')` to get the first one