# regex to find between nth to nth occurrence

Tags: r, regex

I would like to capture the characters between the 1st and 2nd occurrence of '_' in this string:

> C2_Sperd20A_XXX_20170301_20170331

That is:

> Sperd20A

Thank you

Comment: can help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42354232/4137985 ; also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23504780/4137985

Answer (score 7):

We can use `sub` to match zero or more characters that are not a `_` (`[^_]*`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by a `_` followed by one or more characters that are not a `_` (`([^_]+)`) capture it as group (`(...)`) followed by `_` and other characters, replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub("^[^_]*_([^_]+)_.*", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "Sperd20A"
```

Or between the 2nd and 3rd `_`

```
sub("^([^_]*_){2}([^_]+).*", "\\2", str1)
#[1] "XXX"
```

---

Or another option is `strsplit`

```
strsplit(str1, "_")[[1]][2]
#[1] "Sperd20A"
```

If it is between 2nd and 3rd `_`

```
strsplit(str1, "_")[[1]][3]
#[1] "XXX"
```

###data

```
str1 <- "C2_Sperd20A_XXX_20170301_20170331"
```

Comment: is there a matching stringr::str_extract syntax to find a string between the 2nd and 3rd _ in this example (like: strsplit(str1, "_")[[1]][3])?

Comment: @AlexDometrius  Try with `str_replace` `str_replace(str1, "^[^_]+_[^_]+_([^_]+)_.*", "\\1")
#[1] "XXX"`

Comment: What's the purpose of the first asterisk in the expression `sub("*([^_]*_){2}([^_]+).*", "\\2", str1)`?

Comment: @Lyngbakr i guess it was a typo.  I might have intended `^` (updated)

Answer (score 1):

A good option is to use the `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
s <- "C2_Sperd20A_XXX_20170301_20170331"

# (?<=foo) Lookbehind
# (?=foo) Lookahead
str_extract(string = s, pattern = "(?<=_)(.*?)(?=_)")
[1] "Sperd20A"
```