# Extract data with regmatches and move to new dataframe row in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame, `df` that looks something like this:

```
    date      sample
1 29-Apr 1,000 (1/4)
2 29-Apr 1,000 (1/4) 
3 28-Apr 1,970       
4 27-Apr 1,000 (1/4) 
5 25-Apr 1,000 (1/4)
...
```

How can I extract the value in parenthesis and create a new column from it?

I can [extract the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613237/extract-info-inside-all-parenthesis-in-r) in parenthesis:

```
matches <- regexpr("\\(.*?\\)", df$Sample_Size)
fractions_with_parens <- regmatches(df$Sample_Size, matches)
fractions <- gsub("[\\(\\)]", "", more)
```

But this will remove the non-matches, so the vector does match the length of the dataframe's rows. So in this example row 3 will be missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
df$extract <- str_extract(df$sample, "\\(.*?\\)")

df
#    date      sample extract
#1 29-Apr 1,000 (1/4)   (1/4)
#2 29-Apr 1,000 (1/4)   (1/4)
#3 28-Apr       1,970    <NA>
#4 27-Apr 1,000 (1/4)   (1/4)
#5 25-Apr 1,000 (1/4)   (1/4)
```

To extract values within parenthesis you could do:

```
df$extract <- str_extract(df$sample, "(?<=\\().*(?=\\))")
```

Thanks to epi99 for the suggestion.

Comment: To extract from within the paretheses use a regex with look ahead and look behind like `str_extract("ab(123)fg", "(?<=\\().*(?=\\))")`

Comment: Thanks@epi99! Initially thought he wanted to keep the parenthesis, but i'll update to your answer to extract values within.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dplyr`:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(date = c('29-Apr', '29-Apr', '28-Apr', '27-Apr', '25-Apr'),
                 sample = c('1,000 (1/4)', '1,000 (1/4)', '1,970', 
                            '1,000 (1/4)', '1,000 (1/4)'))

df %>% mutate(new = str_match(sample, pattern = '\\d+/\\d+'))
```

Resulting in:

```
    date      sample  new
1 29-Apr 1,000 (1/4)  1/4
2 29-Apr 1,000 (1/4)  1/4
3 28-Apr       1,970 <NA>
4 27-Apr 1,000 (1/4)  1/4
5 25-Apr 1,000 (1/4)  1/4
```

Comment: R base is well tailored for this problem. Anyways, abstracting from this simplistic use case and go to more complex applications this might be a suitable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with convenient functions from `qdapRegex`

```
library(qdapRegex)
df$new <-unlist(ex_round(df$sample, include.markers=TRUE))
df$new
#[1] "(1/4)" "(1/4)" NA      "(1/4)" "(1/4)"
```

If we don't require the brackets, remove the `include.markers`

```
df$new <-unlist(ex_round(df$sample))
df$new
#[1] "1/4" "1/4" NA    "1/4" "1/4"
```