# How can I split a string and ignore the delimiter if it's "quoted"

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

Say I have the following string:

```
params <- "var1 /* first, variable */, var2, var3 /* third, variable */"
```

I want to split it using `,` as a separator, then extract the "quoted substrings", so I get 2 vectors as follow :

```
params_clean <- c("var1","var2","var3")
params_def   <- c("first, variable","","third, variable") # note the empty string as a second element.
```

I use the term "quoted" in a wide sense, with arbitrary strings, here `/*` and `*/`, which protect substrings from being split.

I found a workaround based on `read.table` and the fact it allows quoted elements :

```
library(magrittr)
params %>%
  gsub("/\\*","_temp_sep_ '",.) %>%
  gsub("\\*/","'",.) %>%
  read.table(text=.,strin=F,sep=",") %>%
  unlist %>%
  unname %>%
  strsplit("_temp_sep_") %>%
  lapply(trimws) %>%
  lapply(`length<-`,2) %>%
  do.call(rbind,.) %>%
  inset(is.na(.),value="")
```

But it's quite ugly and hackish, what's a simpler way ? I'm thinking there must be a `regex` to feed to `strsplit` for this situation.

related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751731/parse-in-r-a-file-of-exported-sas-macros/49764659?noredirect=1#comment86563577_49764659)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
library(stringr)
cmnt_rx <- "(\\w+)\\s*(/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/)?"
res <- str_match_all(params, cmnt_rx)
params_clean <- res[[1]][,2]
params_clean
## => [1] "var1" "var2" "var3"
params_def <- gsub("^/[*]\\s*|\\s*[*]/$", "", res[[1]][,3])
params_def[is.na(params_def)] <- ""
params_def
## => [1] "first, variable" ""                "third, variable"
```

The main regex details (it is actually `(\w+)\s*)(COMMENTS_REGEX)?`):

- `(\w+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more word chars
- `\s*`  - 0+ whitespace chars
- `(` - Capturing group 2 start
- `/\*` - match the comment start `/*`
- `[^*]*\*+` - match 0+ characters other than `*` followed with 1+ literal `*`
- `(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `[^/*][^*]*\*+` - not a `/` or `*` (matched with `[^/*]`) followed with 0+ non-asterisk characters (`[^*]*`) followed with 1+ asterisks (`\*+`)
- `/` - closing `/`
- `)?` - Capturing group 2 end, repeat 1 or 0 times (it means it is optional).

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/QQQt4J/1).

The `"^/[*]\\s*|\\s*[*]/$"` pattern in `gsub` removes `/*` and `*/` with adjoining spaces.

`params_def[is.na(params_def)] <- ""` part replaces `NA` with empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are

```
library(stringr)
params <- "var1 /* first, variable */, var2, var3 /* third, variable */"
# Split by , which are not enclosed in your /*...*/ 
params_split <- str_split(params, ",(?=[^(/[*])]*(/[*]))")[[1]]
# Extract matches of /*...*/, only taking the contents
params_def <- str_match(params_split, "/[*] *(.*?) *[*]/")[,2]
params_def[is.na(params_def)] <- ""
# Remove traces of /*...*/
params_clean <- trimws(gsub("/[*] *(.*?) *[*]/", "", params_split))
```

Comment: it doesn't work, you forgot the second element of `params_df`, which is an empty string.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Why is there an empty string?

Comment: because `var2` doesn't have any commented text next to it

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I have modified the code to split the string first

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it in a function and use the (not well documented) `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` mechanism in plain `R`:

```
getparams <- function(params) {
  tmp <- unlist(strsplit(params, "/\\*.*?\\*/(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,", perl = TRUE))

  params_clean <- vector(length = length(tmp))
  params_def <- vector(length = length(tmp))

  for (i in seq_along(tmp)) {
    # get params_def if available
    match <- regmatches(tmp[i], regexec("/\\*(.*?)\\*/", tmp[i]))
    params_def[i] <- ifelse(identical(match[[1]], character(0)), "", trimws(match[[1]][2]))

    # params_clean
    params_clean[i] <- trimws(gsub("/(.*)\\*.*?\\*/", "\\1", tmp[i]))
  }

  return(list(params_clean = params_clean, params_def = params_def))
}

params <- "var1 /* first, variable */, var2, var3 /* third, variable */"
getparams(params)
```

This splits the initial string using `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` (see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/WzyOS9/1)) and analyzes the parts afterwards.

---

This yields a list:

```
$params_clean
[1] "var1" "var2" "var3"

$params_def
[1] "first, variable" ""                "third, variable"
```

---

Or, shorter with `sapply`:

```
getparams <- function(params) {
  tmp <- unlist(strsplit(params, "/\\*.*?\\*/(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,", perl = TRUE))
  (p <- sapply(tmp, function(x) {
    match <- regmatches(x, regexec("/\\*(.*?)\\*/", x))
    def <- ifelse(identical(match[[1]], character(0)), "", trimws(match[[1]][2]))
    clean <- trimws(gsub("/(.*)\\*.*?\\*/", "\\1", x))
    c(clean, def)
  }, USE.NAMES = F))
}
```

Which will yield a matrix:

```
     [,1]              [,2]   [,3]             
[1,] "var1"            "var2" "var3"           
[2,] "first, variable" ""     "third, variable"
```

With the latter, you get the variable names with e.g. `result[1,]`.