# How to extract text inside the brackets in R?

Tags: r, regex

How can I extract all brackets which include a name AND a year?

```
string="testo(antonio.2018).testo(antonio).testo(giovanni,2018).testo(2018),testo(libero 2019)"
```

the desired output would look like this:

```
"(antonio.2018)" "(giovanni,2018)" "(libero 2019)"
```

I do not want to extract (2018) and (antonio)

Comment: What is the rule for extraction here? Please show what you tried to understand your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract info inside all parenthesis in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613237/extract-info-inside-all-parenthesis-in-r)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `str_extract_all` from the `stringr` package with this regex pattern:

```
stringr::str_extract_all(string, 
                         "\\(\\w+([[:punct:]]{1}|[[:blank:]]{1})[[:digit:]]+\\)")

# [[1]]
# [1] "(antonio.2018)"  "(giovanni,2018)" "(libero 2019)"
```

A small description of the regex:

`\\w` will match any word-character
`+`    means that it has to be matched at least once
`[[:punct:]]` will match any punctuation character
`{1}` will exactly one appearance
`(....|....)` indicates one pattern OR the other has to be met
`[[:blank:]]` means any whitespace must occur
`[[:digit:]]` means any digit must occur
`\\(` braces have to be exited.

Answer (score 3):

@loki answer is great! You can also try this, I hope this works for you :)

```
x<-regmatches(string, gregexpr("(?=\\().*?(?<=\\))", string, perl=T))[[1]]

>x

[1] "(antonio.2018)"  "(antonio)"       "(giovanni,2018)" "(2018)"          "(libero 2019)"  

#Extract every nth value. 
>x[seq_along(x) %% 2 > 0]
[1] "(antonio.2018)"  "(giovanni,2018)" "(libero 2019)"
```

Note: Unsure of your complete dataset (i.e. if the structure will always be in nth format. If it is (every 2nd value), this will work on large scale.