# Get all the factor variables from a formula call

Tags: r, syntax, formula, lm

I have a formula that looks as follows:

```
formula <- as.formula(y ~ x + as.factor(z) + A + as.factor(B) + C:as.factor(A) + as.factor(D) + E + F + as.factor(G))
```

I would like to extract all the variable names that have factors to turn them to factors. If I use `all.vars(formula)`, I get all variables and not just the `as.factor()`.

Desired result:

```
factornames <- c("z", "B", "A", "D", "G")
```

I eventually want to feed the selected variables to:

```
# Turn factors into factors
DF[factornames] <- lapply(DF[factornames], factor)
## turn factor variables into dummies
DF <- as.data.frame(model.matrix(phantom ~ ., transform(DF, phantom=0)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some string manipulation to get the column names which are factors.

```
factornames <- stringr::str_match_all(as.character(formula)[3], 'as.factor\\(([A-Za-z])\\)')[[1]][,-1]
factornames
#[1] "z" "B" "A" "D" "G"
```

`([A-Za-z])` part of regex should be changed based on the column names in your data.

Answer (score 1):

We can `deparse` the formula, then `grepexp` everything in parentheses preceeded with "factor" using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8613332/6574038) historic solution.

```
r <- Reduce(paste0, deparse(formula))
el(regmatches(r, gregexpr("(?<=factor\\().*?(?=\\))", r, perl=T)))
# [1] "z" "B" "A" "D" "G"
```